# Connect Rabbitmq to IBM MQ via spring integration

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration

We are trying to integrate RabbitMQ with our system applications (actually MQSeries).
Some applications will not upgrade the broker (MQSeries => RabbitMQ) so we have to transfer messages from RMQ to MQSeries

Using the configuration file (inbound amqp RMQ  => outbound jms MQ) messages are transfered : 150 messages /seconds.
Having a mq channel (MQ => MQ) between two mq servers the is about 12500 msg/seconds.

Two questions :

- Do you have suggestion to optimize the transfert? configuration on the outbound channel (like opening a session on MQ)?
- which version to use in the pom.xml and for the xsd in the configuration file to use latest version of components (for example spring-amqp 2.0.0 without conflicts)?

Thanks for your help

Regards

Eric

**Configuration file**

---

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp"
    xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xmlns:int-jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.7.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


<!-- Channel Definition  -->
<int:channel id="myChannel" />

<!-- Source RabbitMQ -->
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" username="guest" password="guest" addresses="adresse_ip:5672"/>
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="myChannel" queue-names="myqueue" connection-factory="connectionFactory"  auto-startup="true" id="inboundChannelAdapter" />

<!-- Destination MQSeries  -->
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory" >
    <property name="queueManager" value="queue_manager_name" />
    <property name="hostName" value="hostname" />
    <property name="port" value="1414" />
    <property name="channel" value="SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN" />
    <property name="transportType" value="1" />
</bean>
<bean id="jmsQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue" depends-on="jmsConnectionFactory">
    <property name="baseQueueManagerName" value="queue_manager_name" />
    <property name="baseQueueName" value="queue_name" />
    <property name="targetClient" value="1" />
</bean> 

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsOut" destination="jmsQueue" connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory" channel="myChannel"/>
```

**The pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <properties>
       <jms.version>2.0.1</jms.version>
       <mqseries.version>8.0.0.3</mqseries.version>
       <spring.amqp.version>1.7.4.RELEASE</spring.amqp.version>
       <spring.version>4.3.12.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

       <dependencies>

             <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${jms.version}</version>
             </dependency> 

             <!-- ******* -->
             <!--   mq    -->
             <!-- ******* -->
             <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId> 
                    <version>${mqseries.version}</version> 
             </dependency>


             <!-- ******************* -->
             <!-- Spring dependencies -->
             <!-- ******************* -->
             <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
             </dependency>

             <!-- but exclude commons-logging as we're using jcl-over-slf4j -->
             <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                    <exclusions>
                           <exclusion>
                                  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                                  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                           </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
             </dependency>


             <!-- Integration avec MqSeries -->
             <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-integration-amqp</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
             </dependency>

             <!-- AMQP spring dependencies -->
             <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.amqp.version}</version>

             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.amqp.version}</version>
             </dependency>
       </dependencies>  
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the `MQConnectionFactory` in a `CachingConnectionFactory` to avoid creating a new connection and session for each send operation.

Spring AMQP 2.0.0 requires Spring Framework 5.0.0 or later (current is 5.0.1).

Comment: With CachingConnectionFactory:700msg/s ;-)
With version in pom.xml <spring.amqp.version>2.0.0.RELEASE</spring.amqp.version>
<spring.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
We added a new prop for groupid 'org.springframework.integration'
<spring.integration.version>4.3.12.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
because :
spring-integration-core:jar:5.0.0.RC1 or spring-integration-core:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE  are missing
With the version 4.3.12.RELEASE there is an error :
is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 'rabbit:connection-factory' not found
Do you have an idea?

Comment: Don't put XML in comments; it's pretty unreadable; edit the question instead and comment that you have done so. Spring Integration 5.0 will be released in a couple of weeks; right now, the release candidate is available in the Spring milestone repo. 5.0.0.RC1. If you are using AMQP < 2.0.0, you should increase the `prefetch` on the inbound adapter (it has been increased from the old default (1) in 2.0.0).